# removeFromSuperview does't work in the viewwillappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

       NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       NSData *dateListData=[defaults objectForKey:@"DateListData"];
       self.listOfDate=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dateListData];

       UILabel *introductionLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 290, 50)];
       introductionLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
       introductionLabel.text=@"touch the right corner to add";
       introductionLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];

       if ([self.listOfDate count]==0)
       {
              [self.view addSubview:introductionLabel];
       }
       else
       {
              [introductionLabel removeFromSuperview];
       }

       [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

When the `UITableView` has no data, I want to show the "touch the right corner to add"; when UITableView has data, this UILabel will disappear.
After I add the data, then re-appear this view,`[introductionLabel removeFromSuperview]` doesn't work here, but if I close my app, and reopen it, the `UILabel` will disappear.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Try putting this code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Move to instance level then access  //-->       UILabel *introductionLabel ;

Comment: issue solved or not ....

Comment: please put if else condition after all data load and reload.

Comment: What you are trying to do? If your else will execute then you are trying to remove the label from superview that was never added in superview. Because it was just created here not added

Comment: You should just declare your label globally. So it will not initialise every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface className ()
{
    UILabel *yourLabel;
}
@end

@implementaion className

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dateListData=[defaults objectForKey:@"DateListData"];
    self.listOfDate=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dateListData];

if(!yourLabel){
   yourLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 290, 50)];
    yourLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    yourLabel.text=@"touch the right corner to add";
    yourLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
}

    if ([self.listOfDate count]==0)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:yourLabel];
    }
    else
    {
        [yourLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove `introductionLabel` from its superview , without adding it,

Try this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dateListData=[defaults objectForKey:@"DateListData"];
    self.listOfDate=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dateListData];

    UILabel *introductionLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57,     self.view.frame.size.height/2, 290, 50)];
    introductionLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    introductionLabel.text=@"touch the right corner to add";
    introductionLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    [self.view addSubview:introductionLabel];
    [introductionLabel setHidden:self.listOfDate.count]
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface yourClassName ()
{
    UILabel *_introductionLabel;
}
@end

@implementaion yourClassName

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
....
_introduction =[[UILable alloc]init];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dateListData=[defaults objectForKey:@"DateListData"];
    self.listOfDate=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dateListData];

    _introductionLabel.frame=CGRectMake(57, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 290, 50)];
    _introductionLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    _introductionLabel.text=@"touch the right corner to add";
    _introductionLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];

    if ([self.listOfDate count]==0)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:_introductionLabel];
    }
    else
    {
        [_introductionLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}

@end
```

Try like this.... the reason each and every time new label is created...